# @misc reference does not show correctly

Tags: bibliographies

I want to reference [this](https://www.google.com/patents/USD608353) link in my bibliography. Luckily they have a "BibTeX" export which looks like this:

```
@misc{tsai2010inline,
title={Inline microphone for earphone},
author={Tsai, D.M.},
url={https://www.google.com/patents/USD608353},
year={2010},
month=jan # "~19",
publisher={Google Patents},
note={US Patent D608,353}
}
```

Which looks like this:[image]

This is strange, since all my other "@misc" reference works fine, except this one. What am I doing wrong? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Rest of the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.35} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document} 

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum

\pagebreak

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*}{\section}{}{}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}`
```

Comment: What is wrong with it exactly?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? All i can see, is that the `# 19# should probably be removed.

Comment: `misc` does not add `publisher`. It never did in the thirty years it is around. `url` on the other hand is not known to `misc` in general. urls are usually put in the `note` or `howpublished` field.

Comment: `biblatex`  supports an `url`  field for all entry types. It even has some stuff for patents predefined, i think. And if not, it can be added easily.

Comment: *"Luckily they have a "BibTeX" export which looks like this:"* Don't trust them blindly. You are responsible that the bibtex database entry is correct. And this is dependent on the bibliographystyle as well.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by manipulating it a little:

```
@misc{tsai2010inline,
  title={Inline microphone for earphone},
  author={Tsai, D.M.},
  howpublished = "[Online]. Available from: \url{https://www.google.com/patents/USD608353}",
  year={2010},
  month=jan # "~19",
  publisher={Google Patents},
  note={US Patent D608,353}
}
```