# @misc entry does not show the field notes

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to cite the following `@misc` entry:

```latex
@misc{bibliogr61:online,
author = {},
title = {bibliographies - @misc reference does not show correctly - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange},
howpublished = {\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370743/misc-reference-does-not-show-correctly}},
month = {},
year = {},
note = {(Accessed on 12/03/2019)}
}
```

It is shown as:

[image: output]

For some reason, no matter what I do, it does not show the accessed date provided in note filed. Can someone help me out?

Edit: Based on the comment, I am adding some extra information. I am using a LateX template provided by [this journal](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/latex).That's why the style is enforced as `\bibliographystyle{plos2015}`. Any paper published in this journal has the accessed data information if a website is cited.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you employ? (The appearance of the formatted bibliographic entries depends on the bibliography style.)

Comment: @Mico I added the answer of your question in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote,

> For some reason, no matter what I do, [BibTeX] does not show the [contents of the `note` field]. Can someone help me out?

You mention that you use the `plos2015` bibliography style. The file `plos2015.bst` defines the `misc` function, which governs how entries of type `@misc` are formatted, as follows:

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
%  format.editors "author and editor" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  type missing$
    { skip$ }
    { format.type "type" }
    %%{ inbrackets type output }
  if$
  new.block
%  format.publisher.address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
%  format.note output
  new.block
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  output.url % urlbst
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
```

We needn't cover all the details. What's crucial for answering your question is the line

```
%  format.note output
```

You can probably guess what this line of code would do if it were *not* commented out: It would govern the typesetting of the contents of the `note` field. Since the instruction has been commented out, though, the contents of `note` fields in entries of type `@misc` will *not* be typeset. That's it.

Or is it? If you believe strongly that it's essential to typeset the contents of `note` fields, you could remove the `%` character, i.e., re-enable the instruction, and then rerun BibTeX and LaTeX. However, do be aware of the fact that once you submit your paper to PLOS1 (or a similar journal), the contents of the `note` field will once again disappear.

Comment: If I stick to the default settings, but would also like to show the accessed data, then what would be the solution?

Comment: @whitepanda - You could stick both the URL string and the "accessed at" string in the `howpublished` field, i.e., insert the contents of the `note` field at the end of the `howpublished` field. In other words, something like `howpublished = {\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370743/misc-reference-does-not-show-correctly}, (Accessed on 12/03/2019)}`.

Comment: This is indeed a solution, but in this case, I have to update all the citations by hand. I was using the BibTeX extension of Google Chrome which automatically generates a BibTeX entry for the websites. Do you think that there is a more efficient way to do it? Of course, if not, I will go and do it by hand.